# is there a way to get to use method from another class in spring?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Hello i am currently studying and we got a task , we need to modify a video-shop wepsite and we got catalog class and some other classes to help it run with spring like catalogcontroller catalogdataintitlizer etc , here is a cut of the code
`@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMENTS")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7114101035786254953L;

private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

private String text;
static int rating;
static double r_total;


private LocalDateTime date;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Comment() {}

public Comment(String text, int rating, LocalDateTime dateTime   ) {

    this.text = text;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.date = dateTime;
```

` that was from a class called Comment and in this class there are the rating we need to get the Average rating from the rating on every video "note : when someone open a video you can leave a comment with a rating and we need to always add up all the rating that the user leave and then divide it on the number of users ,

`@Entity
public class Disc extends Product {

```
public static enum DiscType {
    BLURAY, DVD;
}
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "deprecation" })
private Disc() {}


public Disc(String name, String image, Money price, String genre, DiscType type) {

    super(name, price);

    this.image = image;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void addComment(Comment comment) {
    comments.add(comment);
}


public Iterable<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}`
```

and here is the other class that might help too here we save the comments to a arraylist "note : i didnt type the code " we just got this project and we need to change few things and i have been spending alot alot of time trying to solve this problem but still no use
i tried to make object from disc in comment and use some of his methods but sadly i got whitelist error from spring when i press on any video so i tried to make the rating static and try to grab it from the other class it worked but when i change from video to other video i end up adding all videos togther " it stacks " i am really new to java and i dont really know what to do now xd ty in advance

Comment: I'm trying very hard to read this and I can't understand a single thing, not to mention, this code is not only not enough, it is not even remotely close to being legal, or useful, the title seems completely out of place with the rest of the question's content. Please try a bit more to explain what's the problem, and modify the code to be [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @adq yh my bad i am new to this sry ;/ the thing is the user create a object on the front end side and then i wanna get that object name or have a wire to it thats the problem i am trying ot solve in the spring :D as i said before i am still learning sorry :D